# Read query parameter from url to do a nginx redirect

Tags: nginx

I have two source URL format and want to redirect both url based on
**color variant** to the destination link with the parameter appended.

**Scenario1**: *www.example.com/pages?abc=123&color=white* which should redirect to www.example.com/variant1?abc=123&color=white

**Scenario2**:  *www.example.com/pages?abc=456&color=red* which should redirect  to    www.example.com/variant2?abc=456&color=red

I have tried with below , it works for one but not for both as its specific. Not able find the solution for both cases, as else doesnt work

```
location = /pages {
    if ($args ~* "&color=white”) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /variant1 redirect;
    } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to do this in Nginx, it'll [defeat some of the advantages that Nginx provides](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).  If you can, it's better to do it within your application code or [Lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module).

If you choose to go forward with `if` statements, you'll want to match against individual `$arg_*` variables rather than `$args`.  In particular, you'll want to use `$arg_color`, which will contains the `color` querystring value.

```
location = /pages {
    if ($arg_color = "white") { return 301 /variant1$is_args$args; }
    if ($arg_color = "red")   { return 301 /variant2$is_args$args; }

    # If we get to this point, there was no match.  You have to keep
    # this very simple and can only use directives documented as being
    # compatible with `if`, or you'll get all sorts of crazy bugs and
    # crashes.
    return 404.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. 404 is handled internally from the server side so there is no issue from my end.